# Nginx WebDAV: Direcory index is forbidden

Tags: nginx, webdav, nginx-config

I am trying for hours to get WebDAV to work on Nginx on Debian Buster. I have created a directory /var/www/html/webdav that is owned by www-data (user/group). I am using nginx-full, that includes http_dav_module and http-dav-ext. I have tried endless combinations of different directories in different locations with different rights but I always get the same error:

```
2019/09/24 14:12:47 [error] 3065#3065: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/webdav/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.1.132, server: _, request: "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.219"
```

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /webdav/ {
        client_body_temp_path /var/cache/nginx;

        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;

        auth_basic "restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        create_full_put_path on;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access group:rw all:r;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to confirm that Nginx is reading the correct configuration.

Comment: Share the exact permissions of that directory.(output of `ls -la` will do)

Comment: Hi Evert, here are the permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 24 14:01 webdav
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Richard, nginx is using the configuration that I posted above.

Comment: Maybe you can try to put the `root` directive inside the `location` block? Check out this example for better compatibility with macOS: https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module#example-3